# Output multiple SDP files using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, h.264, rtp

Is it possible when using FFMpeg, to output multiple SDP files for transcoded streams within a single FFMpeg session?

Below is my ffmpeg command and my attempt to transcode using one input stream, and output 2 rtp streams. First output stream (camera1) is transcoded at lower resolution at 540x360 and the second stream (camera2) is outputting at native resolution.

**.\ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp,tcp -i "rtsp://admin:admin@172.16.250.99/media/video1"**

**-c:v libx264 -vf scale=540:360  -r 5 -maxrate 500000 -bufsize 300000 -minrate 500000 -b:v 500000  -muxdelay 0.1 -threads 4 -sc_threshold 0 -f rtp rtp://172.16.250.156:4321/camera1 -sdp_file "c:\test\camera1.sdp"**

**-c:v libx264 -r 5 -maxrate 500000 -bufsize 300000 -minrate 500000 -b:v 500000  -muxdelay 0.1 -threads 4 -sc_threshold 0 -f rtp rtp://172.16.250.156:4322/camera2 -sdp_file "c:\test\camera2.sdp"**

I was expecting this to output 2 SDP files, but instead I only get camera2.sdp being stored on disk.

Also the camera2.sdp contains video streams for both camera1 and camera2 (see below)

**Is there anyway I can get this command to output the 2 sdp files to disk please?**

SDP:

v=0

o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1

s=Sony RTSP Server

t=0 0

a=tool:libavformat 57.56.100

m=video 4321 RTP/AVP 96

c=IN IP4 172.16.250.156

b=AS:500

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1

m=video 4322 RTP/AVP 96

c=IN IP4 172.16.250.156

b=AS:500

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1